# Bundle install raise error after update to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bundle

I upgraded my application from Rails 5 to Rails 6, but after that when I run `bundle install`, it raise below error in terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    30: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    29: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
    27: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
    25: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
    24: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
    23: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    22: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    21: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    20: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
    19: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:144:in `temporary'
    18: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
    17: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:65:in `run'
    16: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    15: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    14: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    12: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    11: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     9: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     8: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     6: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     5: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/security.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     3: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     2: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': dlopen(/Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/bunto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
```

I try to reinstall ruby 2.5.1 but nothing changed.

What should I do to resolve that problem? Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same error. And this is my fix way, i hope it working with you

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
rvm get stable
rvm reload
rvm reinstall 2.5.1
```

then re-run

```
bundle install
```